# scoped!T() not working for class members

Tags: d

I am trying to use the scoped!T() template to allocate inside the `Program` class to save on an allocation. I can't get it working with the following exception.

```
Error: cannot cast &Scoped([void, void, void, void, void, void, void, void, void, void, void, void, void, void, void, void, void, void, void, void, void, void, void, void, void, void, void, void, void, void, void, void, void, void, void, void, void, void, void, void]).Scoped_store to ulong at compile time
```

I'm not shure if it is by design that one cannot use scoped for a class member or if it is an erorr in the scoped template. If its by design than this is a really crappy error message by the way.

The following code is to demonstrate my problem.

```
import std.typecons;

public class Foo
{
    int i = 0;
}

public class Program
{
    auto myFoo = scoped!Foo();
}

void main(string[] argv)
{
    new Program();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> auto myFoo = scoped!Foo();
> ```

This line will attempt to instantiate a `Foo` class and initialize the `myFoo` field *during compilation*. This is because `scoped!Foo()` is interpreted as a default value, which are always computed during compilation, therefore the compiler attempts to interpret this expression (CTFE). Because `scoped` does some low-level things to work, CTFE doesn't work in this case.

Instead, you should initialize the field at runtime, during class construction:

```
public class Program
{
    typeof(scoped!Foo()) myFoo;

    this()
    {
        myFoo = scoped!Foo();
    }
}
```

The `scoped` documentation actually covers this case. Quoting it:

> Scoped member variables must have
>   type `typeof(scoped!Class(args))`, and be initialized with a call to
>   scoped. See below for an example.

And here is the referenced example:

```
class A
{
    int x;
    this()     {x = 0;}
    this(int i){x = i;}
    ~this()    {}
}

// ...

// Use as member variable
struct B
{
    typeof(scoped!A()) a; // note the trailing parentheses

    this(int i)
    {
        // construct member
        a = scoped!A(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, okay. But shouldn't it be possible to construct `A` at compile time if the ctor was annotated with `pure`? That way the compile could know. Is this not implemented or is it just impossible at all?

Comment: I just realized what I asked. Pure constructors are impossible in the sense of D. But I still think the concept of a constructor which can be executed at compile time must be possible, and therefore this must be possble. Maybe I'm overlooking something.

Comment: `pure` isn't the issue, and `pure` constructors are quite possible as D defines `pure` (i.e. does not access global, mutable state). Classes can even be constructed and used at compile time. However, to be constructed at compile time and then be carried over to runtime, they must be `immutable` (due to issues with allocating reference types on the runtime heap when the runtime heap doesn't even exist yet). Also, `scoped` does low-level stuff that's not allowed during CTFE, so it couldn't even be used with a local variable during CTFE.